# How to use java code in Xamarin Forms to do specific job

Tags: java, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem in Xamarin Forms. I have to make ldap(s) connection to ldaps server. It will be secure ldap connection. I am able to make normal text based ldap connection in Xamarin Form. But i couldn't find a way to make secure ldap connection with using a CA certificate. It is also possible to make this connection in java easily. Is it possible to use a java executable that will get ldap user pass as argument, make ldaps connection and return authentication result to Xamarin Forms code in C#. It will run both in IOS and Android. I guess it should be possible from Java side as its slogan is write once and use everywhere.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: Thanks Jason. Is it also use it for IOS ?

Comment: No, you cannot run Java code in iOS

Comment: If you meant to ask if you could also use Swift/Obj-C code for iOS, the answer is [also yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jason and @Andrew H for your suggestions, Based on the discussion in comment section we understood issue got resolved so we are converting the above comments to Answer for this thread to help other community members.

A Bindings Library is a Java type wrapper assembly that contains Managed Callable Wrappers. Consider the following Java type, MyClass, which we'd want to encapsulate in a Bindings Library:

```
package com.xamarin.mycode;

public class MyClass
{
    public String myMethod (int i) { ... }
}
```

while for IOS, this isn't possible. Instead, we can use swift libraries for binding.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Binding a Java Library - Xamarin | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/)
2. [Bind iOS Swift libraries - Xamarin | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/)